# How do I bind events directly to existing HTML, without using any kind of views, in Ember.js?

Tags: events, binding, ember.js

Ember.js has a great mechanism of binding data to views, of setting triggered event handling in the view, or using a Router. But what I would need is to be able to handle events triggered in already created HTML code (by PHP, server-side).
Let me show you a simple example. I have this code:

`<a id="login" href="#">Login</a>`

I need to be able to route/handle the click on this link so that it gets into my Ember application.
I have been looking for ways to do this, but I can't find any.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this link is inside a DOM element which is a child of the Ember managed element, then you can use the `action` helper:

```
<a id="login" href="#" {{action doSomeStuff}}>Login</a>
```

This `doSomeStuff` event will be sent to your `Ember.Router`, which has to implement the handler in the appropriated route:

```
...: Ember.Route.extend({

  doSomeStuff: function (router) {
    //...
  }
}),
```

If the link is outside your app's scope, you can register handlers on the app-related elements using JQuery:

```
$('a#login').click(function () {
  App.router.transitionTo('the.route.path');
});
```

The `App.router` being injected at Ember app's initialization, you can access it from anywhere.

But let me say that it is not a best practice to transition from outside the router.

Last but not least, you can also pass a context to the `transitionTo` call.

Comment: If by Ember managed element you mean a Ember view, then no, this link is not there. I don't have any kind of Ember views. So, I would be glad if you could go into more detail here.

Comment: So you mean you have an Ember application with no UI? Or do you wish to plug an Ember app as a part of an existing one?

Comment: I would like to bind handlers to existing html elements, which are just there, coming from server-side php. I can't explain this any better.

Comment: But do you have any possibility to custom/enrich the page content? At least you added JS... What is the purpose of your app if it does not display anything? Or does your app displays a small part of the page?

Comment: It will display things, using HTML5 history, when possible, without page reload. This way I find it optimal, to generate views server-side, so that I keep the same content.

Comment: I updated my answer, trying to provide you as info as possible, but I don't get the big picture of your needs. Hoping this will help...

Comment: This is probably the closest I can get to what I want, so thanks!